# Cannot import ES6 NPM module directly in to Ember CLI

Tags: javascript, ember.js, d3.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to use [d3-arrays](https://github.com/d3/d3-arrays) in a project. The module itself includes both original ES6 modules and a UMD build. I would expect to be able to add this directly as a dependency to my ember-cli project and have it available, but that is not the case.

I've seen suggestions that are over a year old saying to use `ember-browserify`, and others suggesting making a shim, but AFAIK this would really only be ideal if it were a bower dependency, and bower seems to be on the way out.

For the sake of correctness, how can I just import this module as though it were part of my project and use it as `import {mean} from 'd3-arrays` without needing to convert it to another package format first?

**I've tried** making a shim which just exports the imported UMD code:

```
// index.js
var d3ArraysExports = require('d3-arrays');
d3ArraysExports.name = 'd3-arrays-shim';
module.exports = d3ArraysExports;
```

Ember finds this module just fine, but it never gets added to the require entries list.

*If there is some design decision in Ember CLI as to why this doesn't work, please point me to it.*

Comment: Does your shim enable named imports (such as `import {foo} from "bar"` too? Named imports is a known caveat of `ember-browserify`, but with that installed you can just do `import d3arrays from "npm:d3arrays"` and use the methods through that (d3arrays.mean([1,2])) etc.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I want to use some of the modules of d3.js like d3-arrays, d3-scale and etc. What it is the preferred solution for this. Do I need to create a shim lib for all of them? Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an elegant solution to this:

I created a shim library which imports the ES6 sources from d3-arrays and makes them available to broccoli. Here's an example:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  name: 'd3-arrays',

  treeForAddon: function() {
    var packagePath = path.join(this.project.addonPackages['ember-d3-arrays-shim'].path, 'node_modules', 'd3-arrays');
    var d3ArraysTree = this.treeGenerator(packagePath);
    return this._super.treeForAddon.call(this, d3ArraysTree);
  }
};
```